# Force software keyboard to show on focused input in HTML load

Tags: javascript, html, smartphone, soft-keyboard

With simple HTML page, how to open programmatically software keyboard after document loaded on smartphones ?
For better user ergonomics, the goal is to focus on the first input with the softkeyboard already open. Just to write and continue.

**Without any interaction of user**,
and after page is loaded,
neither .focus() .click() and trigger touchstart/touchend/mousedown/mouseup open the system soft keyboard.

An idea ?...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script>
    var loadDOM = 0;
    var loadload = 0;

    function fullloaded() {
      if (loadDOM == 1 && loadload == 1) {
        var el = document.getElementById('test2');
        triggerEvent(el, 'touchstart');

        var el = document.getElementById('test2');
        triggerEvent(el, 'touchend');

        var el = document.getElementById('test2');
        triggerEvent(el, 'mousedown');

        var el = document.getElementById('test2');
        triggerEvent(el, 'focus');
        el.focus();

        var el = document.getElementById('test2');
        triggerEvent(el, 'mouseup');

        var el = document.getElementById('test2');
        triggerEvent(el, 'click');
        el.click();
      }
    }

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
      logEvent('DOMContentLoaded');
      loadDOM = 1;
      fullloaded();
    });

    window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
      var logEvent('load : All resources finished loading!');
      loadload = 1;
      fullloaded();
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="test2" placeholder="_default_" />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: when the page loaded you want to focus the first input tag?

Comment: el.focus(); active focus on field, 
but not open softkeyboard (user must click again on field to open softkeyboard)

Comment: You can't, the user need to click on the input. So on mobile you can't call `focus()` or call `blur()` so it can be focused by the user.

Answer (score 0):

After testing around with several devices, short answer is **you can't open the softkeyboard on load of the webview**, because the user hasn't "touched" any element on the screen.

After the user touched the screen the **focus()** on any input text element should bring up the keyboard, but unfortunately that first opening of the keyboard on the load of the page without the user touching the screen is not possible, so even a setTimeout or delay on this action also wouldn't work unless the user touches the screen within that timeframe.

Answer (score -1):

try this..

```
<input type="text" autofocus>
```

in javascript try this

```
$(function() {
var el = document.getElementById('.class');
    el.focus();
});
```

Comment: not working, (same code in the ask) autofucus attribute change nothing